# sDNA - cycle model based on start and end elevations rather than 3d shapefile

Tags: line, road, sdna, center

I want to run a cycle roundtrip model in sDNA. My file is a road center line (RCL) map, containing z coordinates (start Z, end Z - image attached).

The RCL vector file is shown by GRASS GIS as 3D, but is flat (elev = 0). Consequently, s=0, s=1, etc. yield identical results applying the cycle model (Hmf and Hmb, and all other output variables).

How could I accomplish running the cycle roundtrip model with such a file, instead of a true 3D vector?

I have converted the vector to 3D based on endpoints, but sDNA network preparation fails - many links seem to be separated vertically.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't say what went wrong with your conversion to 3d. However you could use an sDNA hybrid metric based on CYCLE_ROUNDTRIP and adapt it to estimate link slope from its endpoint elevations.

The default CYCLE_ROUNDTRIP metric is printed to sDNA's output when you run it:

```
lineformula=_a=0.2,_s=2,_t=0.04,_slope = hg/FULLeuc*100,_slopefac = _slope<2?1:(_slope<4?1.371:(_slope<6?2.203:4.239)),_slopeb = hl/FULLeuc*100,_slopefacb = _slopeb<2?1:(_slopeb<4?1.371:(_slopeb<6?2.203:4.239)),_trafficfac = 0.84*exp(aadt/1000), euc* (_slopefac^_s + _slopefacb^_s) * (_trafficfac^_t) + _a*67.2/90*ang*2;juncformula=0.2*67.2/90*ang*2
```

The above makes use of sDNA builtin variables `hg` (height gain) and `hl` (height loss). Note that `hg` and `hl` do not assume the link has even slope - they accumulate total height gain and loss over the link such that gains and losses do not cancel. However the CYCLE_ROUNDTRIP formula *does* use them in a way that assumes even slope.

In the example below I replace them with user defined temporary variables (which must start with underscore, otherwise sDNA will go looking for them in the input data) `_hg` and `_hl`

Note also that the above formula isn't applied to a whole link at once. It is applied at most to half a link (in discrete space mode) or smaller fractions thereof (in continuous space mode). So to compute mean slope for the link we compute elevation change between its endpoints and divide by the *full* network-Euclidean length of the link `FULLeuc`:

```
_slope = _hg/FULLeuc*100
```

where _hg was computed from your endpoint data `TO_Z`, `FROM_Z` as follows

```
_elevchange=fwd?TO_Z-FROM_Z:FROM_Z-TO_Z,_hg=_elevchange>0?_elevchange:0
```

(`fwd` tells us whether this link is being traversed forwards, hence which way round FROM and TO should be; we then set any negative elevation change to 0 to get height gain `_hg`).

*Later* in the final expression, recalling that we may not be computing a whole link at a time, we multiply the various factors by `euc` the length of the fraction of link under consideration.

The full formula:

```
lineformula=_a=0.2,_s=2,_t=0.04,_elevchange=fwd?TO_Z-FROM_Z:FROM_Z-TO_Z,_hg=_elevchange>0?_elevchange:0,_hl=_elevchange<0?-_elevchange:0,_slope = _hg/FULLeuc*100,_slopefac = _slope<2?1:(_slope<4?1.371:(_slope<6?2.203:4.239)),_slopeb = _hl/FULLeuc*100,_slopefacb = _slopeb<2?1:(_slopeb<4?1.371:(_slopeb<6?2.203:4.239)),_trafficfac = 0.84*exp(aadt/1000), euc* (_slopefac^_s + _slopefacb^_s) * (_trafficfac^_t) + _a*67.2/90*ang*2;juncformula=0.2*67.2/90*ang*2
```