# Modelling elevation in 3D link-network for sDNA in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, network, arcscene, sdna

I have a 3D link network model (multiple grades/levels joined by vertical links) that I would like to analyze using sDNA. Since the topography is uneven, I would like to account for the terrain before running the sDNA analysis. I attempted the command `Interpolate to Shape` but got the error

> x input geometries were not interpolated, possibly due to not being
> within the surface extent.

I understand it is due to the way the command works,

> if a feature falls entirely off the surface, it will not be written to
> the output.

Is there another way to account for terrain in a 3D link network model for sDNA analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way forward is to fix the terrain model. What would you prefer to happen to links that are not within the surface extent - assign them an elevation of zero? You could create a second feature class containing all the features dropped by Interpolate Shape (in ArcGIS you could do this using Select Features By Location), add elevation of zero to them, and merge with the successfully interpolated features.

That said, it sounds like with your multiple levels you may want some custom way to compute elevation anyway. If your levels are stored as z coordinates then Interpolate Shape will flatten everything onto the terrain surface. So you may prefer to store the height of each link start and end in an attribute field, then reconstruct the correct elevation somehow after interpolating. You'll need to do something outside of sDNA for that step, or code your own preprocessing.

Without further understanding your needs I can't give a definitive answer though I can point out this: elevation matters for two reasons in sDNA.

1. Firstly to determine which links connect to one another. Links are deemed connected if they share the same endpoint x,y,z *and* same grade separation. Grade separation is not interpreted as elevation but links will only connect where it matches.
2. Secondly if you are using 3d data in your metric. Note that turn angles are always computed in 3d, based on z values in the links. If your metric makes use of height gain (`hg`) and height loss (`hl`) builtin variables these are also computed from z values. If you want to make use of 3d data stored as attributes, rather than z values, this is possible with hybrid metrics and there is an example here: [sDNA - cycle model based on start and end elevations rather than 3d shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413306/sdna-cycle-model-based-on-start-and-end-elevations-rather-than-3d-shapefile/413466#413466) . This could be another way forward for dealing with your two elevation sources (building level plus terrain) e.g. you could add terrain height change to building height change. Though I imagine to display results you would prefer a combined model where z represents terrain+building anyway, rather than flatten one of those elevation sources, hence the suggestion above to fix the elevation model before running sDNA.

Hopefully that will help to clarify your aims and make some progress.

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: To clarify what I need, I have two elevation sources (building level+terrain) that I need to account for. I'd like to confirm if I understand  (sDNA - cycle model based on start and end elevations rather than 3d shapefile) right. So step one would be to store height of start and end of each link as attributes, and step 2: sDNA hybrid metric CYCLE ROUNDTRIP. Am I right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to model - it strikes me as unlikely you are trying to analyse cyclists in a building? If the answer is 'pedestrians', then do you want changes in level to factor into their decisions of whether or not to make a journey and which route to take?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to analyse pedestrian paths in a district and how building levels and terrain change their route choice. Yes, ideally changes in level should factor in the analyses if their route choice.

Comment: Ok. So you'll need to figure out how to build a 3d pedestrian network model, before you can use sDNA to analyze it. This is potentially not straightforward. Do you have 3d models of the building interior networks already? Or do you need to draw them first e.g. in autocad map3d or arcgis pro? How do you handle coupling of buildings to terrain? bear in mind building floors are level even though underlying terrain may slope, so interpolate shape may not be the best choice for interior networks unless your terrain is fairly level.

Comment: Once you have the model you need to define a metric. I don't think any of the builtin metrics in sDNA make use of elevation change, apart from the cycle ones. With the right preprocessing and use of one-way links you could potentially encode it as a custom metric. The other option is to use sDNA+ to define your own hybrid metric which can direcly use the elevation change. If going the latter route it gives another possibility you may prefer for handling building interiors, instead of constructing a full 3d network you could use the 2d network draped over terrain plus maybe incorporate the...

Comment: ...grade separation data in your hybrid metric, in a manner similar to the post you linked above. But then you'd be stuck with the problem of visualising outputs so maybe you would prefer a full 3d network anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Here are my follow-up questions: I have drawn the 3D network already using Rhino, so is there a way to account for terrain in ArcGIS, or do I re-draw the network keeping the terrain levels of the polylines in mind?

Comment: 'With the right preprocessing and use of one-way links you could potentially encode it as a custom metric.' Could you please elaoborate on this?